# Keeping aware of Google Analytics API deprecation

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Our custom GA app broke the other day due to the deprecation of the v. 2.3 of the GA API. We want to mitigate that in future.

How can we be kept apprised of when a version of the API is going to be taken down? I checked for an email in the account linked to GA, but there was no warning this was going to happen.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [GA blog](http://analytics.blogspot.com/) RSS feed and/or join the [google-analytics-api-notify](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fgroup%2Fgoogle-analytics-api-notify&ei=IVILUKvfLYKK8QT8neznCg&usg=AFQjCNEKlUdGESFTlBxu869B3pwgj_goBg) group.

One or both of those will keep you up to date on the changes.